No notifications from calendar
Im not sure what happened but for some reason I started to get event invitations as emails instead of calendar notifications to my phone.
I try to check all the settings like:

I have 2 accounts (gmail and Icloud). Gmail is set to Fetch data while Icloud to Push. (Gmail has no push for me).
The calendar is synced with Icloud.
In my icloud calendar->the send and receive are set to notification.

Any ideas what might be the error?
I feel like it all started since i subscribed to icloud.
